# Picture tag preventing DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am using JavaScript to create a function to manage 1x and 2x image rollovers.

I have a collection of images nested in a `div` tag to group and reach via JavaScript more efficiently...

i.e. `var rollOverCollectionA = document.getElementById('roll-over-collection-a').querySelectorAll('img');`

But to be more exact each of these images are nested in a `<picture>` tag. See below:

```
  <div id="roll-over-collection-a">
    <a href="#">
      <picture>
        <img id="hover-1" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_1.jpg?$staticlink$"
          srcset="/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_1.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_1@2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
        />
      </picture>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <picture>
        <img id="hover-2" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_2.jpg?$staticlink$"
          srcset="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_2.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_2@2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
        />
      </picture>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <picture>
       <img id="hover-3" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_3.jpg?$staticlink$" srcset="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_3.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_3@3x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"/>
      </picture>
    </a>
  </div>
```

And this is the script:

```
var on = function(event, elem, callback, capture) {
  if (typeof elem === 'function') {
    capture = callback;
    callback = elem;
    elem = window;
  }
  capture = capture ? true : false;
  elem = typeof elem === 'string' ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
  if (!elem) return;
  elem.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
};

function rollOver(elem) {
  if(document.getElementById(elem).src = `images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_${elem.slice(elem.length-1)}.jpg?$staticlink$`) {
    document.getElementById(elem).src = `images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_${elem.slice(elem.length-1)}.jpg?$staticlink$`
  }
  if (
    (document.getElementById(
      elem
    ).srcset = `images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_${elem.slice(
      elem.length - 1
    )}@2x.jpg?$staticlink$`)
  ) {
    document.getElementById(
      elem
    ).srcset = `images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_${elem.slice(
      elem.length - 1
    )}@2x.jpg?$staticlink$`;
  }

}

function rollOut(elem) {
  if (document.getElementById(elem).src = `images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_${elem.slice(elem.length-1)}.jpg?$staticlink$`){
    document.getElementById(elem).src = `images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_${elem.slice(elem.length-1)}.jpg?$staticlink$`
  }
  if (
    (document.getElementById(
      elem
    ).srcset = `/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_${elem.slice(
      elem.length - 1
    )}@2x.jpg?$staticlink$`)
  ) {
    document.getElementById(
      elem
    ).srcset = `images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_${elem.slice(
      elem.length - 1
    )}@2x.jpg?$staticlink$`;
  }

}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var rollOverCollectionA = document.getElementById('roll-over-collection-a').querySelectorAll('img');
      rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);
    console.log(rollOverCollectionA);
      for (let i = 0; i < rollOverCollectionA.length; i++) {
       on('mouseover', `#${rollOverCollectionA[i].id}`, function(){
         rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id);
       });
       on('mouseout', `#${rollOverCollectionA[i].id}`, function(){
        rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id);
       }); 
      }
});
```

The script seems to work i.e. image rollovers successful, when the `img` element is not nested in the `picture` tag but when the `img` tag is nested in the `picture` tag it doesn't work i.e. image rollovers unsuccessful,.

Checking the `console.log(rollOverCollectionA);` 
I do see that the collection of image elements but I realized there is a flaw in my `rollOver` & `rollOut` functions.

The way I have it, I am checking if there is indeed a `srcset` attibute and its value. What I would like is a way to know if the picture attribute has loaded the 2x in the browser.

**Note:**

I tried removing each of the `img` tags out of the `picture tags` and it works!

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please define *"it doesn't work"* in proper detail. That explanation is virtually meaningless

Comment: @charlietfl Good point. I revised my question.

Comment: Note your if statements are doing assignments not comparisons, ie `.src = ` when they should be `.src == `

Comment: @PatrickEvans Believe it or not the way I have it works.

Comment: @MrLister https://codepen.io/antonioOrtiz/pen/aQoMNQ?editors=1010

Comment: @MrLister the third one will work because its not in the `picture` tag...